# Compare folder contents with another folder and delete

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have 1000 files in a folder and similar named files in another folder. The objective is to have identical filenames in both folders but keep the file extension.

I would like to run a script to compare each folder's content (except their file extension) and if they are not in on folder If there is a file called BILL in folder1 but not in folder2 it deletes the file in one of the folders.

**Example:**

- C:\TempFolder1\RandomFile1
- C:\TempFolder2

If `RandomFile1` does not exist in `TempFolder2` it deletes it from `TempFolder1` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... this script assumes you aren't looking recursively through subfolders, ignoring directories as well underneath either parent folder... it works by pulling the file list, then comparing each folders child files' **BaseName** with the list of BaseNames from the other, then removing the unique ones:

```
$folder1 = "C:\TempFolder1"
$folder2 = "C:\TempFolder2"

$files1 = Get-ChildItem $folder1 | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $false}
$files2 = Get-ChildItem $folder2 | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $false}

# Remove unique file baseNames from $folder1 that don't exist in $folder2
$files1 | Where-Object {$files2.BaseName -notcontains $_.BaseName} | Remove-Item -Force

# Remove unique file baseNames from $folder2 that don't exist in $folder1
$files2 | Where-Object {$files1.BaseName -notcontains $_.BaseName} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: I will try that out when I can, it looks great, thank you!

In each folder there is 1000 files with no sub directories so should be ok.

Will this script work if I place it in folder I want to apply it in and use %~DP0 where $folder1 is? or do I have to specify the full location?

Comment: Since you're targeting 2 folders, you're best off using full paths for consistency IMHO. It's definitely possible to have it run in the context of the folder that it's in, but you'd still need to write the full path for the second folder and you would need to add in an exclusion rule so the script itself isn't purged... Easier to keep this at a central scripts folder then update the paths as needed prior to running

Comment: I have tested that script and it works a treat. really appreciate your time! unfortunately it doesn't come natural to me so im not fluent in it. top man, high five!